# save the audio from url locally for play later

Tags: iphone, ipad

How can i save the audio from url locally for play later. I can stream the audio using avplayer but can't save it locally and play later .I tried with avurlasset. Can anyone help me?

This is my code by which i tried to save locally:

> > > here i streamed the audio using  avplayer
> > >       //code for saving the locally

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context

{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        AVPlayerItem * item = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
        if (item.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
        {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"audio.m4a"];
            asset=player.currentItem.asset;
            NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
            // 5 - Create exporter
            AVAssetExportSession *assetEx = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]  initWithAsset:player.currentItem.asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];//tried with  asset2 also
            assetEx.outputURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
            assetEx.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
            assetEx.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
            [assetEx exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
                int status = assetEx.status;
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self exportDidFinish:assetEx];
                });
            }];


        }
    }
}
but there is no file created in the documents directory.
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: You can store your audio in Document directory to play it later. When you want to play it just give that path as audio url.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.@ShahPaneri: you are correct . But i could't get the streamed data to save.It is playing in avplayer.is there anyway to get data from avpalyer??